# jtable deleteConfirmation : false error

Tags: jquery, jtable

In my page I don't want any delete confirmation message to be shown.
I tried with
 `deleteConfirmation:false`

but I am still getting the confirmation alert box.
Please suggest some workarounds to achieve this.
Thanking you in advance.

here is the code sample :

```
title : 'WorkArea List',
paging : true, //Enable paging
pageSize : 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
sorting : false, //Enable sorting
jqueryuiTheme : true,
openChildAsAccordion : true,
deleteConfirmation : false,
actions : {
                listAction : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/globallink/ajax/grid?type=repoLoad',
                deleteAction : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/globallink/ajax/g rid?type=repoDelete',
                updateAction : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/globallink/ajax/grid?type=repoUpdate'
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting deleteConfirmation to false, use the following code

```
deleteConfirmation: function (data) {
      data.deleteConfirm = false;
}
```

Please note that `data.deleteConfirm` is a boolean value that indicates whether to show a delete confirmation message or not (default value is true).

FYR - http://jtable.org/ApiReference/GeneralOptions#genopt-deleteConfirmation